# How to navigate to a Post on a RESTful site on MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a hold of using RESTful on MVC 4 to give me an API I can use on WP/Android/Iphone, so for starters (This method will be remade later, this is just for testing purposes)

I have a WP app that communicates with the server and sends it a json object and recieves a json object using restclient

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = "http://*****.***/API/Account/Login";

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        User user = new User
        {
            UserName = "muhcow",
            Password = "123456"
        };

        request.AddBody(user);

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("jo");
        });
```

And then I have my servercode which I first tried making a normal controller and then just making a controller called account and an action called login taking a httppost, and that worked fine, but from what I can read its not the way to do rest!

So I tried making a controller inheriting from apicontroller but now I got issues even getting routed to the Post action in the LoginController

So post is in Domain\API\Login\LoginController

And the post action is like so

```
    public string Post(Login loginModel)
    {
        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password))
        {
            loginResponse.Success = true;
            loginResponse.Token = "11111111111111111";

            return Json.Encode(loginResponse);
        }

        loginResponse.Success = false;
        loginResponse.Error = 1;
        return Json.Encode(loginResponse);
    }
```

but with the current code that is not hit (Checking with breakpoints)

I havent changed the MapRoute yet so its just

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "API_default",
            "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you'll need an `ApiController`-specific route set up using the [RouteCollectionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routecollectionextensions.maphttproute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), like this (instead of the route you have):

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "API_default",
   routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

Just a quick note on the "not the way to do REST" comment though - this is actually a pretty hot topic.  I wouldn't worry too much about how [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) you are being.  Consider what RESTful architecture helps solve, and see if that matches the problem you're addressing (and to what degree you want to adopt the principles).

There's lots of great literature out there but I found [this post](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) from Martin Fowler to be particularly helpful in getting my head around it.

Comment: I have it working, but not with areas, dont seem like thats supported out of the box yet

Comment: It does work with areas, you just have to make sure you use MapHttpRoute on the route collection instead of MapRoute on the context.  It's probably working without areas in your solution because the API route gets added automatically, but not with a new area (currently).  I'm using API controllers in areas with no problems.

Comment: Also, note that even the way you mark "id" as optional is slightly different when routing to ApiControllers